# instantaneous forward rates vs forward LIBOR rates

Tags: libor-market-model

HJM describes the behavior of instantaneous forward rates while BGM describes the behavior of forward Libor rates. From concept perspective, I understand forward libor rate are like forward Libor rate with different tenor, e.g 3M. They are directly tradable in the market with quotes? But what is the instantenous forward rates?

Comment: Do you want the definition for instantaneous forward rates?

Comment: I found the definition of instantaneous forward rates over the internet. But I am still confused about how is instantaneous forward rates different from forward libor rates?

Answer (score 3):

The forward Libor rate at time $t$ is the forward rate over a certain accrual period $[T, T+\Delta]$, where $\Delta$, in years, can be 3 months or 6 months, and is defined by
\begin{align*}
L(t, T, T+\Delta) = \frac{1}{\Delta}\left(\frac{P(t, T)}{P(t, T+\Delta)}-1 \right),
\end{align*}
where $P(t, u)$ is the price at time $t$ of a zero coupon bond with unit face value and maturity $u$.

The instantaneous forward rate is the forward Libor rate over an infinitesimal accrual period. That is,
\begin{align*}
f(t, T) &=\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}L(t, T, T+\Delta)\\
&=\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(t, T) - P(t, T+\Delta)}{\Delta}\frac{1}{P(t, T+\Delta)}\\
&=-\frac{\partial P(t, T)}{\partial T}\frac{1}{P(t, T)}\\
&=-\frac{\partial }{\partial T}\ln P(t, T).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you Gordon! So this instantaneous forward rate is basically not directly observable in the markets at all?

Comment: @Quant2015:  No, it is not.